# Multiple APK is not working for x86 architecture

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, x86, multiple-apk

I have built multiple APK for publishing on Google Play. I built with in Unity (ARMv7 and x86). It built success and has appear on Google Play.
I have tested it with ARMv7 device, it's good. But for x86 device (I use Zenphone 2), why can this device not download from Google Play.

Comment: What is your current build settings.

Comment: I only modified the Device filter is x86 and change version code